# No route matches "/index". Simple issue?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

New to all coding worlds and new to RoR. I have been doing a tutorial and ran into some issues last night. A friend of mine helped with a few of them. I asked a few here. And yet this one baffles me. I cannot find the issue of it.

The page loads, it shows what needs to be shown. But when I press a link on there it results in this:

```
    Routing Error

No route matches "/index"
```

So I did `rake routes` and I got this

```
Dennis-Buizerts-MacBook-Pro:gpoff dennisbuizert$ rake routes
site_index GET /site/index(.:format) {:controller=>"site", :action=>"index"}
site_about GET /site/about(.:format) {:controller=>"site", :action=>"about"}
 site_help GET /site/help(.:format)  {:controller=>"site", :action=>"help"}
      root     /(.:format)           {:controller=>"Site", :action=>"index"}
```

This is in my routes.rb

```
root :to => "Site#index"
get "site/index"       
get "site/about"
get "site/help"
```

I tried adding `map.connects` and `match` but that didn't seem to resolve it. 
And my development.log says the follow:

```
Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-08-28 10:05:51 +0200
DEPRECATION WARNING: Disabling sessions for a single controller has been deprecated. Sessions are now lazy loaded. So if you don't access them, consider them off. You can still modify the session cookie options with request.session_options. (called from <class:ApplicationController> at /Users/dennisbuizert/Sites/gpoff/app/controllers/application_controller.rb:3)
  Processing by SiteController#index as HTML
Rendered site/index.html.erb within layouts/application (1.6ms)
Completed 200 OK in 5ms (Views: 4.3ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)


Started GET "/index" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-08-28 10:05:52 +0200

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches "/index"):


Rendered /Users/dennisbuizert/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.0.10/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/routing_error.erb within rescues/layout (0.8ms)
```

Comment: If no one posts a reply, you might try [http://webdevrefinery.com/](http://webdevrefinery.com/). There is a bunch of RoR acolytes that hang around there at odd hours.

Comment: How is this link to `/index` created? Because the root should not be `/index` but just plain `/`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
get 'index' => "site#index"
```

instead of

```
get "site/index"
```

Comment: Thanks. This fixed it. Is this a work around? Or will I discover later on that this is a good solution?

Comment: @dbuizert, Imm, this could be workaround, but If you don't change route, you need to change links to `/site/index` or `/` instead of `/index` in views or layout file.

Comment: Actually, frankly, you should not be reaching `/index` at all. Just `/` should be sufficient. This solution indeed makes sure that you can type `/index` but normally that is never needed.